# How to setup an LDAP server in local LAN to create common address book for OSX and Windows computers?

Tags: address-book, ldap, openldap

We're using a PC and a MacBook at home which are connected via a local network. We'd like to have a "master" address book for both computer, so that when contact information is changed on one of the computers, the change can be automatically also synced with the other computer.

At the moment, we're using the MacOS X 10.6 AddressBook.app and Outlook XP on Windows XP for managing addresses, but we'd be also willing to switch from outlook to something different, if it would make things easier...

*How can I set up an LDAP server on the PC or on the Mac which makes available addresses, email addresses, phone numbers, birthday dates and notes of contacts to the computers in the (private LAN) network?*

- which (free) software is best suited? OpenLDAP?! Or are there tools in Windows or OS X which let me create such a server directly?
- can the server import the local address data from Apple Address Book and Outlook XP?
- where can I find a good tutorial?

*note:*

I do **not** want to sync or store any contact information in or via the internet for privacy reasons!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to just buy OS X Server (19.99$) and set it up. Either that or just try out the varies free alternatives and spend some time configuring it. I assume most basic things will work between OS X and Windows since most of this is standardized.

Comment: interesting - thanks! I did not know that OS X Server has such a low price, however on its systemrequirements it is written that I need a Mac running Mountain Lion.. so is it necessary to have a license for OS 10.8 to buy and use OS X Server? BTW, at the moment I do not want to reinstall OS X (too many things installed and configured which I urgently need and not time for fiddling around), so using OS X server is not an option for me at the moment, but in general an interesting idea.

Comment: You need Mountain Lion if you buy from App Store. OpenLDAP seems like a lot of hassle but you could search for a guide. You can easily install OpenLDAP through homebrew or macports.

Comment: I read in several discussions/forums, that OpenLDAP (and also LDAP in general) is not very intuitive and easy to set up.. is that true? Is there a better alternative or a system with a good GUI that simplifies things?